# UITableView with limited number of cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an `UITableView` with ±10 different `UITableViewCells` to display full information about an object (description cell, photos cell etc.). So when `UITableView` is loaded, I do not need `UITableView` cells to be reused. Wouldn't performance be better if I somehow store `UITableViewCells` and prevent `cellForRowAtIndexPath` from being called? If so, what is the way to achieve alike behaviour?

Comment: There is Static Cell available to use for tableviewController. do some RND on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can not prevent cellForRowAtIndexPath from being called if you are gonna use UITableView. It is a UITableViewDataSource function and it's not an optional one. Otherwise, you won't be able to populate your tableview.

What you can do is use switch case on indexpath.row in cellForRowAtIndexPath and return necessary cell.

Comment: yeap. that's how I do this, the question is if scrolling performance would be better if somehow store cells instead of reusing.

Comment: unless you are doing some complex operation while displaying the cells or making any network calls the performance should be affected. and the cells will be reused only if the same cell is called at two different positions/indexpath in tableview which can not be displayed at the same time (without scrolling).

Answer (score 0):

You could try by increasing prototype cell in Storyboard. each cell assign new cell identifier and you need to keep array of identifier matching their index with storyboard.

Your cellForRowAtIndexpath will reduced to:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[cellIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Note: cellForRowAtIndexpath method will always called. In above case you can put your data in storyboard itself.
Check similar case at https://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/